# ¿Cómo hago mi localhost público?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hice una base de datos de series de televisión en `WAMP`.

Para acceder a mi base de datos introduzco:

```
http://localhost:8080/capitulos/index.php
```

Como sabrán, sólo puedo acceder desde mi ordenador, mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo acceder a esta página desde otros ordenadores?

Comment: He leído algo de poner la IP, de modo que sería 192.168.x.x:8080/capitulos/index.php pero me sale error 403 Forbidden. He probado a meterme en el httpd.conf y cambiar el Directory pero me sigue saliendo lo mismo. No sé qué hacer...

Comment: Revisa https://ngrok.com/

Comment: También tienes que quitar la protección de wamp, viene activada por defecto, no es recomendado usar eses servidores para producción

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te notifica `error 403` porque `WAMP` bloquea las consultas fuera de tu ip local.

En el archivo `httpd.conf` de Apache quita el `denny for all` por `Allow for all`.

Y para que los usuarios de Internet pueden entrar debes configurar tu router de tal manera que el `puerto 80` re-direcciones hacia tu servidor, entra en el y en el apartado `DMZ` lo podrás configurar.

Lo más óptimo sería que tu proyecto en producción, alquilases un HOST, ganarás en rendimiento y seguridad.

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer un DMZ en tu router que apunte a la ip local de tu equipo, lo otro es que compres un hosting con dominio que es una solución económica y rápida de hacer lo que quieres

Answer (score 1):

El error 403 es probablemente debido a tu configuración Apache, ya estás en contacto con el servidor web. En httpd.conf verás algo así (dependiendo de la versión de Apache):

```
# onlineoffline tag – don’t remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Si cambias `127.0.0.1` por la palabra `all`, otras máquinas pueden conectarse.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que jugar con el `Router` y poner la IP en el `DMZ` luego en un `DNS` como el que encuentras en http://www.noip.com configuras que apunte la url aqui te dejo un tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sikF6sd1wW4 (aunque utilizan `XAMPP`, la lógica es la misma) Aquí hay una pregunta muy parecida https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501056/how-to-access-a-website-using-apache-from-internet-using-no-ip con su respuesta.

Sin embargo, a modo de recomendacion, utilizar un hosting gratuito para mostrar tus proyectos seria una buena idea: `Hostinger.es` por ejemplo es sencillo de utilizar.